# Fresh installed Ubuntu16.04.1 stucks at reboot screen

Tags: 16.04, reboot

My screen stays at this [image: state] for so long after I installed Ubuntu16.04.1 on Dell XPS15 and tried to reboot.

What should I press to exit this state? Force shutdown by long pressing the power button would be my last resort.

Comment: The long pressing the power button should be the last recourse.  But when it's the only option, there's nothing else you can do.  I always try things in a similar order as this to clear stuck screens.  `ctrl c`, `ESC`, `ctrl+alt+del`, `tap the power button to send API shutdown`, and when all else fails, I `long press the power button` as last result.

Comment: Thank you very much. This sequence is what I am looking for.